# Null Pointer in Typeface.createFromAsset()

Tags: android, android-fonts

My Folder Structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Code for font:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets() , AppContants.ROBOT_MEDIUM);
```

My Source set:

```
 sourceSets {
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/res/xml']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/assets']
        }
    }
```

Getting Null pointer for this Typeface instance.

Comment: Check the answer below @nitesh

Comment: Change to: "assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']"

Answer (score 2):

Add fonts folder to your path. Move your .ttf files to the fonts folder.

```
 sourceSets {
    main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/res/xml']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/assets/fonts']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your font file in `assets/fonts` directory an then,
Simply use :

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
                fontPath);
```

where `fontPath` is the path to your font file in assets folder.

```
fontPath = "fonts/<your_font_file_name>"
```

Hope this Helps!